# Google Chrome crashes on fresh 12.04 install

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

I just installed 12.04 and the first and only thing I did was install google-chrome-stable. When I run the program through terminal with `google-chrome` I get a few error (the first 3 or so lines below) then as I browse I get OmniBoxGtk errors and finally (normally when a Flash app or video is loaded) the browser crashes entirely which I think is represented by the last line below. I am brand new to Ubuntu so any help in getting this resolved is much appreciated!

```
josh@josh-NV75S:~$ google-chrome
[5137:5162:0305/235507:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(624)] Failed to get name owner. Got org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name
[5137:5162:0305/235507:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(624)] Failed to get name owner. Got org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name
[5137:5137:0305/235507:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(529)] Failed to call method: org.chromium.Mtpd.EnumerateStorages: object_path= /org/chromium/Mtpd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.chromium.Mtpd was not provided by any .service files
[5137:5137:0305/235507:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0305/235514:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0305/235538:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0305/235614:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/000006:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/000155:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/000334:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/000415:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/000458:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/000946:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/001209:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
xdg-settings: unexpected/missing argument
Try 'xdg-settings --help' for more information.
[5137:5137:0306/001448:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/001503:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/001508:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/001538:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/001540:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/002021:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/002604:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/002612:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/002616:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[5137:5137:0306/002633:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a practical method, I suggest you **remove Google Chrome** which is causing problems **and use [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/) instead**.

It's simply "the open-source project behind the [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) browser" with the same features minus Google's branding, the built-in PDF viewer, the built-in Flash Player and access to some user data.

As explained here: [www.webupd8.org/2012/09/new-chromium-stable-and-development.html](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/new-chromium-stable-and-development.html)

You can add the stable PPA and install Chromium using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Or, if you want the latest dev builds, use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Only if you still experience similer problems persist, you might need to go into some more technical stuff.